# How to create a reference to System.Array holding strings in C#

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010, mono, system.array

I have an interesting question regarding C# code.
Basically I have to call a method

```
BCI2000AutomationLib.IBCI2000Remote.StartupModules(ref System.Array)
```

Using Visual Studio 2010 the following code compiles and works perfectly:

```
// Startup modules
string[] modules = new string[3];
modules[0] = "SignalGenerator --local";
modules[1] = "DummySignalProcessing --local";
modules[2] = "DummyApplication --local";
ok_conn = bci.StartupModules(ref modules);
```

Now porting this to a game engine (e.g. Unity 3D) requires some stricter C# code since it uses Mono C# compiler. So for the same code i get the following compilation error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   *'BCI2000AutomationLib.IBCI2000Remote.StartupModules(ref System.Array)' has some invalid arguments Argument 1: cannot convert
>   from 'ref string[]' to 'ref System.Array'*

Can you please give an advice on how to rewrite this code block to a more strict coding to resolve the stated error?

Comment: I can't get the above to compile - you're missing a parameter name on the declaration, and even with that fixed, I get what I expected - an error "cannot convert from 'ref string[]' to 'ref System.Array'". Can you produce a short and complete example that compiles in VS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the type of you variable to System.Array

```
// Startup modules 
Array modules = new string[3] 
{
    "SignalGenerator --local",
    "DummySignalProcessing --local",
    "DummyApplication --local"
};
ok_conn = bci.StartupModules(ref modules);
```

Your method StartupModules takes a ref Array as argument ; it can set the variable to any other Array. Not necessarily a string Array, it could be an int[]. That's why you cannot call with a variable typed as Array of string.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for the explanation.
I was able to compile and run in the Mono C# compiler without problem.


Unfortunately Unity3D outputs the error:
_ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR (Int32 errorCode)
(wrapper cominterop) BCI2000AutomationLib.BCI2000RemoteClass:StartupModules (System.Array&)
(wrapper cominterop-invoke) BCI2000AutomationLib.BCI2000RemoteClass:StartupModules (System.Array&)_

But I guess I have to ask the Unity and BCI2000 developers on this error.

Comment: Glad to help you, ask them or post a new question here.

Answer (score -1):

String Array program, taking string from user:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i,j;
        string[] str = new string[10];
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Name of your friends");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            str[i] = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Array["+i+"]="+str[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```